# A term for the set of all possible drawings of graphs

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, terminology

It is well-known that every graph can be drawn in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that every two lines intersect only in vertices (there are no superfluous intersections). In fact, every graph has uncountably many different drawings, and in some applications, the differences may be substantial (for example, if a road network is drawn, there is a big difference between a road of 10 meters and a road of 100 meters, although each of them can represent a single edge).

However, not all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ are drawings of graphs. For example, if a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional elements, or infinitely many intersections between lines, then it cannot represent a finite graph.

My question is: what is a term for all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that can be obtained by drawing a finite graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drawing of a graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called an embedding of a graph into $\mathbb{R}^3$. You could look up on “CW-complex” or “simplicial complex” for a particular topological spaces that captures the embedding of graphs.

Comment: A CW complex captures only the topology, but in some cases, the exact shape can be important. For example, if you plot paths in a map, it is important whether each edge is short or long, straight or curved. I am looking for a term that captures the actual drawing - not only its topology.

Comment: How about "isometric embedding of ...(whatever types of graph you meant)... into R3"?